# PackageMaker error could not copy resources to en.lproj

Tags: xcode, resources, packagemaker, build-error

I placed my app bundle in PackageMaker and tried to build it and now I am getting this error:

> error could not copy resources to en.lproj

Any ideas?  Thanks

Screen Shot:
[image]

Comment: where are you seeing the error?  in the "verification log" (in PackageMaker) or in the Install log in an installer that you built?

Comment: I added a screenshot, I guess it is the Verification log in PackageMaker.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it has something to do with hitting "Edit Interface" and then adding a background.  At the bottom of the background it says "en", but I'm not sure what I need to add to make this work.  This is just a guess for anyone who is trying to help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that I moved my icon file that was connected to the background.

Comment: You say that, but that was exactly the same problem for me as well, so you just saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: In my case it was the Multilingual licenses that had moved! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!